# QGIS: Update geometry via geom_from_wkt('POINT(X,Y)') - how to correctly parse string columns?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry

The columns containing X and Y strings look like

`-1234,56`

So far i tried:

`geom_from_wkt(concat('POINT(',replace("wbr_komplett.X",',','.'),',', replace("wbr_komplett.Y" ,',','.'),' )'))`

and also:

`geom_from_wkt('POINT( 
'|| replace("wbr_komplett.X",',','.') ||','||replace("wbr_komplett.Y" ,',','.') || ' )')`

Both to no avail. After saving the edits and closing the session the desired features still don't have a valid geometry. The layer in question is a Geopackage. As far as i can tell both queries are correct - also they wouldn't be executable if they were not.

Comment: it should be `geom_from_wkt('POINT(X Y)')` (i.e. remove the coma between X and Y)

Comment: I've tested your query - maybe the problem is that you missed whitespace? I mean when I print geom_from_wkt (concat('POINT(',replace('-1234,56',',','.'),',',replace('-1234,56' ,',','.'),' )')) in QGIS field calculator, I get NULL otherwise I print  geom_from_wkt (concat('POINT(',replace('-1234,56',',','.'),',',' ', replace('-1234,56' ,',','.'),' )')) I get <geometry: Point> in preview!

Comment: @JGH is correct, WKT format without comma between x y coordinates

Comment: Actually space ' ' did the trick. Sloppy me, I should've looked closer to the example shown on the right panel of field calculator. However without the space it did not work with either query. I can only guess it might be due to the dash prefix in the coordinates. So feel free to post your comment as answer I'll mark it then. An additional thought from my side on that comma orgy: It would be nice to have a more pythonic synthax avaliable like '{}'.format().

Comment: Can you write this in an answer?